# WinRT: Repeatedly opening a file for read raises UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I'm having a weird issue in accessing files cached on disk in my WinRT application. Whenever a user clicks on an item, I first check whether this already exists on disk (and downloading it in that case).

Now, weirdly, if this is called again a second time, I get an UnauthorizedAccessException when ReadBufferAsync() is called. Anyone got an idea why?

Thanks!

Daniel

```
            StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
            var buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
            var dataReader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
            retval.data = new byte[buffer.Length];
            dataReader.ReadBytes(retval.data);
            BasicProperties basicProperties = await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
            retval.lastModifiedTime = basicProperties.DateModified.DateTime;
            dataReader.Dispose();
```

Comment: How are you setting permissions for the first phase (where you download the file)? Showing the code for that might be helpful.

Comment: You might want to put the `dataReader` in a `using()` block rather than manually calling `Dispose()`

Comment: Keith - I'm not setting any permissions, just using standard. Actually, it seems that the system is keeping the file open and I don't seem to have any way of instructing it not to.

Comment: Micky - apart from this being more elegant, would it change the status quo?